Apache2 not using the username set in envvars (Ubuntu)
So I set a specific user within the enviroments variables file "/etc/apache2/envvars"
export APACHE_RUN_USER=someuser

But when I run the function "echo exec('whoami');" it shows "www-data", the default user.
I checked Apache's settings with "apache2 -S" and it shows that both the User and Groud are "not_used"
User: name="someuser" id=1001 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used

I don't know why they're not being used, and I know the user itself is working because I can log into a SFTP session with it.

Setting variables does not magically set the user in the configuration files. Make sure main configuration file is using that variable for directives User and Group or set them manually otherwise. Otherwise paste the relevant Apache HTTPd configuration where User and Group directives are defined.
